# Blender mesh 3d print feature

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

How to solve these problems I dont know.

How to solve thin faces, zero edges, zero faces and bad contig edges problems?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Then you click on the one of this button in Edit mode, Blender will select the corresponding faces or edges, indicating where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about what these mean.

Here's a video tutorial that may help explain the options of 3D Printing Tool Box which you can use before exporting out of blender to check the stl.

Blender Mesh Fixing | 3D Printing Tool Box Explained
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rgrLWFUjlk

```
Time Stamps:
    0:00 - The 3D Print Tool Box | Blender Mesh Analysis.
    1:03 - How To Scale By Volume & Bounds.
    2:40 - Non-Manifold Edge Explained.
    3:35 - Bad Contig. Edges Explained.
    4:20 - Intersect Face Explained.
    5:34 - Zero Faces Explained. 
    6:19 - Zero Edges Explained. 
    7:18 - Non-Flat Faces Explained. 
    9:10 - Thin Faces Explained.
    10:10 - Sharp Edge Explained. 
    11:30 - Overhang Face Explained. 
    12:15 - A Little Bug To Watchout For.
    13:19 - Automatic Blender Mesh Fixing & Exporting.
    14:15 - Mesh Design Things To Keep In Mind.
```